# I am contented with the way it is

Tags: phrase-usage

Let's say your are contented with your current room's decoration, simple yet easy to move around. Can you say:

> "I am contented with the way it is"

Is this the correct phrase for that? Let's not mention the other aspects of my introduction...

Comment: The answer is yes. Questions where the answer is "yes" aren't very good ELL questions, though. Can you provide more detail about why this is confusing to you?

Comment: I would just say "I am *happy* with the way it is." Your example, while OK, would be more natural using "content" (adjective) instead of "contented" (verb).

Comment: @joiedevivre, usually it's happy that is being used, and 'happy' is already a fixed word while contented came from content, which is from noun to adjective... though it my hunch that I'm right, I just wanna make sure coz sometimes that 'hunch' of mine is wrong hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two sentences are both grammatically correct and mean the same thing:

> I am content.
> I am contented.

Because [content](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/content_2) is also a verb in modern-day English, it's okay to use its past participle as an adjective. You can use many past participles as adjectives. However, the word "content" is also an adjective.

I haven't done enough research to say for certain, but I suspect this is probably because *content* **used to** be a past participle in an obsolete verb conjugation.

[Etymologically](https://www.etymonline.com/word/content) speaking *content* and *contain* are synonyms. At root, they both mean "held together." But the important point is that the root that means *to hold* was most likely an irregular verb in Latin. All I know for certain is that *tenir* is an irregular verb in modern French.

In summary, it is fine and grammatically correct to say "I am contented" in English. But it is somewhat rare to say that, because *content* survives as an adjective and means the same thing, so it's more common to say "I am content."

I should also note that while it's more common to use *content* after a linking verb, for some perverse reason, it's more common to use *contented* as the adjective preceding a noun:

> He feels **content**.
> The **contented** child fell asleep.